# Solution verification about a question involving direct sums and containment

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Consider the following question:

> Suppose that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and that $\alpha: V \rightarrow V$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map such that $\alpha^n=1$ for some $n>1$. Show that if $V_1$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $\alpha\left(V_1\right) \subset V_1$, then there is a subspace $V_2$ of $V$ such that $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$ and $\alpha\left(V_2\right) \subset V_2$.
> [Hint: Show, for example by picking bases, that there is a linear map $\pi: V \rightarrow V_1$ with $\pi(x)=x$ for all $x \in V_1$. Then consider $\rho: V \rightarrow V_1$ with $\rho(y)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^i \pi \alpha^{-i}(y)$.]

I have an argument that differed from the hint. Here is how it goes. Since $\alpha ^n =1$, it follows that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ devices $t^n-1$. So $0$ is not an eigenvalue, and hence $\alpha$ is a bijection. We are told that $\alpha(V_1) \subset V_1$. But the image is also a subspace. By bijectivity it follows that $\alpha(V_1) = V_1$. Now let $\{e_i\}_i$ be a basis for the $V_1$. Then they can be extended to be a basis for all of $V$, say $V$ has basis
$$
\{ e_1, ... ,e_n , f_1, ... f_m\}.
$$
Clearly the span of the $f_j$ gives a subspace. Call it $V_2$. By construction the direct sum equation holds. As $\alpha$ is a bijection, due to dimensional reasons, we require $\alpha (V_2) = V_2$. QED

I think there is something wrong with this argument as it is first too simple for a question that is meant to take 25-30 minutes. Moreover, it doesn't use the hint.

Can someone check if the argument holds? Moreover, if it does, could someone elaborate on the second part of the hint? I understand the first part but I don't see how considering $\rho$ leads to $V_2$. Any hints or thoughts towards it will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Your $\alpha (V_2) = V_2$ has no reason to hold. Only the dimensions are equal.

Comment: Hi  @AnneBauval, thank you for the comment. We have that $\alpha (V_1 \cup V_2) = V$ and that $\alpha (V_1)= \alpha (V_1)$ therefore as $V_1$ and $V_2$ are disjoint, we have $alpha(V_2)=V_2$. I think this is ok?

Comment: $\alpha (V_1 \cup V_2) \ne V$, $V_1\cap V_2\ne\varnothing,$ and again, $\alpha(V_2)\ne V_2.$

Comment: I think I understand now, the issue is that $V_1 \cup V_2 \neq V$ but $V_1 + V_2 =V$. Do you have any ideas of the meaning of the last function in the hint?

Comment: Hint: check that $\rho$ is a projection onto $V_1$ and commutes with $\alpha.$ Then consider its kernel.

Comment: This question looks pretty tricky! It's essentially making you prove Maschke's theorem from representation theory. The point is that $\rho$ will be an "$\alpha$-equivariant" projection onto $V_1$, which automatically gives a complement of $V_1$ - $\ker \rho$, by facts about linear maps. It'll be $\alpha$-stable, ie $\alpha(V_2) \subseteq V_2$. This will be more motivated if you go on to learn some representation theory! For your approach, I think a sanity check like $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ could help. (Here we must have $V_1, V_2$ being the two eigenspaces.)

Comment: It seems like  questions on pure maths topics on exams seem to be proving theorems or cases of higher year material. On another note, I found this theorem https://i.imgur.com/VkuARlI.png in my notes. I think it doesn't imiddietly apply as there need not be an eigenvalue with an eigenspace of dim 1. I am currently trying to apply te comment above yours. Again, thank you for the input on my questions.